# How to calculate the maximum pressure that can be applied on a rubber wall sheet?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, material-science, stress-strain

I am planning on building a water barrier made out of rubber sheet for a school project, however, I was wondering how can I calculate the maximum pressure that the rubber wall sheet can handle. Is there a specific formula for it?

For the water, I have already calculated the maximum hydrostatic pressure. Is this the maximum pressure applied on the wall?

Here is the diagram, where the yellow part is the rubber wall sheet.

[image]

Comment: please show a diagram of the geometry

Comment: Hello, i've added now the diagram :)

Comment: This is not a simple system to analyze.  The main deformation and stresses in the sheet are going to be in the plane of the sheet, resulting from the net load distribution normal to the sheet.  To analyze it properly, you first need to have measured the deformational behavior of a flat sheet subject to tensile loads.  From this, you would be able to calculate the stress distribution of the normally loaded sheet.  You would also need to measure (off-iine) the failure behavior of the sheet as a function of the state of stress.

Comment: Thank you for this info,
but can i ask what sources or book can you recommend to get the formula for this, especially for this deformational behavior of the flat sheet? Thank you so much tho, i really appreciate it :)

Comment: I would recommend a book on "Strength of Materials."  You would have to derive the relationship yourself.  I would start with a simpler problem:  replace the square window with a round window and the variable pressure difference with a constant pressure difference.  I would assume a parabolic displacement variation like $y=\delta\left[1-\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^2\right]$ where $\delta$ is the displacement at the center of the window (the maximum displacement), r is the radial distance from the center, and R is the radius of the window.  From this I could calculate the strain distribution, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir! I'll take note of this.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sa=N&rls=en&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=Fichter+W.B.+%22Some+Solutions+for+the+Large+Deflections+of+Uniformly+Loaded+Circular+Membranes%22,+NASA+technical+paper+3658.+(1997)&client=safari&ved=2ahUKEwjbz_KB_NvwAhVMMVkFHfpvCD84FBCMmQR6BAgKEAE&biw=1100&bih=552

Answer (score 0):

I used a very crude approach using the Strength of Materials approximation I described in my comment, and got the following for the nominal stress in the rubber membrane:  $$\frac{\sigma}{E}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{P}{E}\frac{R}{h}\right)^{2/3}$$where $\sigma$ is the stress, E is the elastic modulus of the rubber, P is the pressure difference across the membrane, and h is the rubber thickness.  For your square window, I would replace R with S/2.  To use this equation, you would still need to know the critical stress to cause the rubber to fail.

Comment: Thank you for this information, Sir!

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the maximum pressure on a rubber wall sheet, use the formula: Pressure = Force/Area. Determine the force applied to the sheet and divide it by the surface area in contact with the rubber. Make sure to use consistent units (e. g., Newtons per square meter) for accurate results. Additionally, consider the material's elasticity and thickness for a comprehensive assessment.